# Ubuntu gave up waiting for suspend/resume

Tags: suspend

Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my device has bring this message every time it restarts. And I am dumbfounded on an (initramfs) terminal that doesn't accept many commands suggested by other solutions that I have seen online.

Also grub  doesn't allow any of the commands suggested to solve this problem.
My system is a Nitro 5 laptop. I changed the internal m.2 128 GB to 2 TB m.2
And dual booted Windows and Ubuntu, each owning 1 TB of storage. It worked fine for a month or two. I then added sleep functionality to Ubuntu then that happens. Windows is working fine.

How to get back to my Ubuntu operating system?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Changed the drive (SATA) mode to AHCI in UEFI settings and it's working fine again.

Comment: AHCI controls power management too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem which occured after I changed the swap partition.  I followed the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473884/540756

> If a swap partition is deleted (e.g. on purpose when migrating from HD
> to SSD), the file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume should be either
> completely empty or read RESUME=. Delete any UUID number. RESUME=NONE
> is not valid.
>
> $ sudo gvim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
>
> The initial RAM filesystem requires updating for these changes to take
> effect:
>
> $ sudo update-initramfs -u